# Breaking relationship cycles when constructing paths in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-theory

[image: Graph layout]

The graph above can be created with this Cypher script:

```
CREATE
    (t1:Token {content: "Jake"}),
    (t2:Token {content: "wanted"}),
    (det:Token {content: "the"}),
    (t3:Token {content: "dog"}),
    (t4:Token {content: "neighbours"}),
    (t5:Token {content: "had"}),
    (t1)-[:PRECEDES {index: 0}]->(t2),      
    (t2)-[:PRECEDES {index: 1}]->(det),      
    (det)-[:PRECEDES {index: 2}]->(t3),      
    (t3)-[:PRECEDES {index: 3}]->(det),      
    (det)-[:PRECEDES {index: 4}]->(t4),
    (t4)-[:PRECEDES {index: 5}]->(t5);
```

This is the graph of the sentence "Jake wanted the dog the neighbours had".  Note that the word 'the' appears twice.  In this model each node represents a particular word (not an instance of a word).  However, we should be able to reconstruct the individual sentence, given that we have the index of the sentence in the word encoded in a property on the `:PRECEDES` relationship.

Is there any way to query this sentence as a path in Cypher, using the `index` property to avoid entering a cycle on the node representing `the`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to propose an alternate schema, as the one you have will fall apart and/or perform horribly once you add more sentences.

1) For each sentence, create a node to represent that sentence.

2) Create a relation from that node to each word node in the sentence, and add an index property on the relationship. (You may use a first/end relationship for the first and last element, or add that as a property for easier Cyphers)

3) Run Cyphers on your "sentence" nodes instead. Order words by relation Index

This will make your data much easier to read, query, and write.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tezra for the sentence nodes.

With your model, I have a funny result

```
 MATCH (t2:Token) 
 WHERE NOT (t2:Token)<-[:PRECEDES]-(:Token)
 WITH t2
 MATCH (t2)-[pr:PRECEDES*..]->(t3:Token)
 WITH t2, last(pr).index AS pos, t3.content AS txt ORDER BY pos
 RETURN t2.content, pos, txt
```

the last two words are repeated. I presume a longer sentence would generate more noise
You can have a sentenceId in PRECEDES

I advise to have :Sentence as start node, with relations to words.

Later, you will reach the "over-connected node" problem (with, the, on, ...)
Have a look at the NLP plugin from graphaware